# Android external library

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I would like to create such as "Common" library for android, but I have problems with configuring it in Intellij IDEA.

Let's say, what I would like to have ActivityHelper class which looks like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ActivityHelpers
{
    public static void unlockScreen(Activity activity)
    {
        Window window = activity.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    public static void clearFlags(Activity activity)
    {
        Window window = activity.getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}
```

I added new module, "Gradle: Java Library" under Android section, then set up Android API 19 Platform as Module SDK in Modules settings.

Looks like editor can see `import android.app.Activity;` , but compilation fails with:

```
Error:(3, 19) Gradle: error: package android.app does not exist
```

etc.

Can it be done somehow?

Comment: that's not a java library, that's an android library, i guess. (which is like java, but with a different classpath for compilation)

Answer (score 0):

Look for an "Android Library" module rather than a "Java Library" module when creating your module.

Comment: I was looking for that and haven't found, so I decided to create Java module. I'll try one more time

Comment: It's been a while since I've tried with IntelliJ rather than Android Studio. But, IntelliJ 12 used to have the option for an Android library (as well as Android app).

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

You can create library project in Intellij IDEA 13 by `Gradle: Android Module` and then selecting `Mark this project as a library`